# контактная форма для wp

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите какой плагин лучше использовать для контактной формы темы wordpress?
Или вообще правильнее *contact.php* (экземпляр страницы) создавать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую Contact Form 7, очень гибкий инструмент

Comment: Спасибо! Пожалуй им и воспользуюсь)